# dropdownlistfor is not displaying error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc

`DropDownListFor` is not throwing validation error message when default option on page submit. It is not allowing to submit the page but not throwing the error. Other validation  messages are shown except for dropdownlist.

```
public class CallLogViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select")]
    [Display(Name = "Details of Issue/Incident")]
    public IEnumerable<IssueCategory> IssueDetails { get; set; }
    public int SelectedIssue { get; set; }

    public CallLogViewModel()
    {
        HomeRepository hr = new HomeRepository();
        IssueDetails = hr.GetIssueCategories();//gets the list
    }       
}

public class IssueCategory
{
    public int UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new CallLogViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IssueDetails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIssue,  new SelectList(Model.IssueDetails, "UniqueId", "Issue", Model.SelectedIssue), "Please Select",new { @class = "form-control" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueDetails,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You applying `ValidationMessageFor()` to the `SelectList`, not the property your binding to.

Change the model to

```
public class CallLogViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IssueCategory> IssueDetails { get; set; }
    // Apply the attributes to the property your binding to
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select")]
    [Display(Name = "Details of Issue/Incident")]
    public int SelectedIssue { get; set; }
    ....
```

and change the view to bind the label and validation message to the `SelectedIssue` property

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedIssue, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIssue, new SelectList(Model.IssueDetails, "UniqueId", "Issue"), "Please Select",new { @class = "form-control" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedIssue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Note also the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is not required (the `Selected` proeprty of `SelectListItem` is ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` method. but since you using a view model, your property should be `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IssueDetails { get; set; }` (which you populate i the GET method, and the view is simply

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedIssue, Model.IssueDetails, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" } )
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. It's working great. Just a quick question, the dropdownlist items should be the  ones listed in the database table Issuecategory with uniqueid and issue as columns. So  I have just  used it. It's working fine with selectlistitem, but why cannot we use the datatable IssueCategory as part of ienumerable

Comment: Please suggest the best practise, using selectlistitem or issuecategory class as ienumerable? and why?

Comment: You can, but its better practice to use `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> IssueDetails { get; set; }` in your view model (and set it in the GET method using `model.IssueDetails = new SelecltList(hr.GetIssueCategories(), "UniqueId", "Issue");` (or `model.IssueDetails = hr.GetIssueCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.UniqueId.ToString(), Text = x.Issue });`